# Convert Monthly Data to Quarterly in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have monthly data that is grouped by ID, which also has a parent ID. The data looks like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'parent_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -99999, -99999, -99999],
                     'id': [123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123],
                     'data_1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0],
                     'data_2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0],
                     'period': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                     'date': ['2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31',
                              '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30',
                              '2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28'],
                     'quarter': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

data_2 = pd.DataFrame({'parent_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -99999, -99999, -99999],
                     'id': [234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234],
                     'data_1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0],
                     'data_2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0],
                     'period': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                     'date': ['2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31',
                              '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30',
                              '2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28'],
                     'quarter': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

data = data.append(data_2)
data = data.reindex()
```

I have a function, which works when I have one id, but when I introduce more than one ID, the summing is not unique to one ID.

```
def convert_to_quarterly(df, date):
    """Aggregates 3 months of data to a quarterly value."""
    columns = ['data_1', 'data_2']
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df = df.set_index('date')
    df_quarterly = df.resample('Q')[columns].sum()
    df_quarterly['date'] = df_quarterly.index
    df['date'] = df.index
    df.drop(columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = pd.merge(df, df_quarterly)

    return df

convert_to_quarterly(data, date=pd.to_datetime('2017-06-30'))
```

What do I need to do to make Pandas sum only on individual groups of IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already done so you need to make your date column formally a datetime type. Then you can use groupby followed by resample.

```
data['date'] = data['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
data.set_index('date').groupby('id').resample('Q')['data_1', 'data_2'].sum()

                data_1  data_2
id  date                      
123 2017-06-30      10      10
    2017-09-30      90      90
    2017-12-31     110     110
    2018-03-31       0       0
234 2017-06-30      20      20
    2017-09-30     180     180
    2017-12-31     220     220
    2018-03-31       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I was looking for! I can't believe I missed the groupby step. You're a lifesaver! I'll be sure to buy your book & follow you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TomCusack Sure thing. Thanks for the support. I actually found a bug because of this problem. You shouldn't have to put the date column in the index with `set_index` because resample has an `on` parameter, but it doesn't work in this case. [See here for github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17813)